# ASP.NET MVC2 custom dateTime format helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I have a question on how to create custom View Helpers.
I would like, in my Index View, to change my default dateTime format. I want to write my own Helper as I thought it was easy like in e.g. PHP.
I did:

1. Created Class:

   ```
   public static class CustomViewHelpers
   {
       public static MvcHtmlString returnDateString(string format, DateTime date)
       {
           return MvcHtmlString.Create(date.ToString(format));
       }
   }
   ```
2. I added it to the web.config,
3. I used it like that:

   ```
    <p><em>
       Birth date</em>
       <%: CustomViewHelpers.returnDateString("D", Model.Birth_Date); %></p>
   ```

But I always get the error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

But I think it is a wrong error because when I remove my line it works correctly and I see there are these ")" marks.
Can you explain to me why this kind of helper does not work? Maybe you know a good tutorial on how to write your own helpers in ASP.NET MVC2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `;` from the call to the helper.

`<%: ... %>` hold *expressions*, not statements, and should not have semicolons.

Comment: When I remove this ; I have:

Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'Adventure_v1.Helpers.CustomViewHelpers.returnDateString(string, System.DateTime)' has some invalid arguments 

But I do not understand why?

Comment: Yes I can read (O_o) the error message but first parameter is "D" so it is string and the second it is DateTime in my database so I dont understand why it returns this error. Maybe in view it is changes somehow but for what?

Comment: Ok, I do not know why but it does not have DateTime type in view, but I made it work. Thanks for sarcasm rather to explain why it is like this... But thanks anyway. I did: DateTime.Parse(Model.Birth_Date.ToString())

Comment: That wasn't sarcasm.  The first error message doesn't have any useful information.  I suspect that your model type was wrong, but I need other error message.

Comment: By the way, it is interesting for me why ; is so important and why when I had it, I did not have this error message. Thanks SLaks once again! <shame> Sorry I missed "other". Sorry once again for misunderstanding

Comment: With the semicolon, the entire line makes no sense - it gets transformed to `Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(something;));`.

Comment: aaaaaaa OK Now I understand! Thanks a lot!